# How to remove top panel of ubuntu 16.04 desktop

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I developed a GUI program which runs automatically in full-screen mode on ubuntu 16.04 computer after login. The user must not switch to other program, and never logout. So I needs to remove or hide the top bar(panel) of ubuntu desktop. I searched the ubuntu forms, found no answer. Does anybody know how to do it?.